# Dimension error in LSTM Tensorflow, how to proceed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have a sentence in the form of :

```
P ∈ d×P
```

Where:

- d is the dimensionality of word embedding.
- P is no. of tokens in sentence.

I am trying to get the hidden representation of P using LSTM

```
H ∈ l×P
```

Where:

- l is the dimensionality of the hidden vectors

I tried the following

```
H_para = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[N, P ], name='para')
```

Embedding tensor of dimension [A, V ] and BasicLSTMCell(l)  l is hidden units.

I am getting a dimension error:

```
with tf.variable_scope('Para'):
    para_list = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(H_para))
    para_embed = [tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, w) for w in para_list]
    Para, para_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, para_embed,dtype = tf.float32)
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Could you post (1) a minimal reproduction (i.e. a snippet that anyone can run) and (2) the actual error message and stack trace?

Comment: I think i have got the problem and fixed it.@AllenLavoie

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler might be complaining about the visibility scopes of your variables. As you see, "para_" is added to the variable names from the error report you quote. It is likely this is not what you intended.

I could probably tell you more if you provided the full error message and a minimal (not) working example of your code.

Comment: hello @Szczypawka it's not  about the scope. actually tf.nn.rnn is working fine but with tf.nn.dynamic_rnn its giving an error. if you want change the variable/scope name i don't have a problem with that.